# VB.Net One button to show hidden buttons

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm a complete noob at this, but does anyone know a simple code that will get hidden buttons to show apon clicking another button?

Thanks!!

Comment: Under the click event of the button, simply set `hiddenButton.Visible = True`

Comment: You need to better describe your project if we were to help you. I'll give you a general answer and say you can loop over controls of type button, then if they are visible=false you make them visible=true.

Answer (score 0):

In the click event of the button that you want to unhide the other buttons just put

```
Button1.Visible = True
Button2.Visible = True
```

Etc.

Replace Button1 with the actual button name.

That’s it